# Não consigo achar o motivo do FormatExcpetion

Tags: c#, mysql

Pessoal boa noite to com um probleminha em um programinha basico de teste que estou fazendo alguém poderia me ajudar ?

> Erro: A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto. (FormatException)
>
> em System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>      em System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
>      em System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
>      em System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
>      em MySql.Data.Types.MySqlInt32.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.WriteValue(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, Object val, Int32 length)
>      em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.Serialize(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
>      em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex)
>      em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)
>      em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()
>      em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
>      em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      em MiniCrud_Aula_PC.DAO.cadastrarCarro(Carro c) na C:\Users\Filipe\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MiniCrud_Aula_PC\MiniCrud_Aula_PC\DAO.cs:linha 41
>      em MiniCrud_Aula_PC.frm_Principal.Salvar_Cadastro() na C:\Users\Filipe\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MiniCrud_Aula_PC\MiniCrud_Aula_PC\frm_Principal.cs:linha 239
>      em MiniCrud_Aula_PC.frm_Principal.bt_Salvar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) na C:\Users\Filipe\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MiniCrud_Aula_PC\MiniCrud_Aula_PC\frm_Principal.cs:linha 62
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>      em System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>      em MiniCrud_Aula_PC.Program.Main() na C:\Users\Filipe\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MiniCrud_Aula_PC\MiniCrud_Aula_PC\Program.cs:linha 18
>      em System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>      em System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>      em Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>      em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>      em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

```
    private const string insertCarro = "insert into tbl_Carro (marca, modelo, ano, cor, estado, valor) values (@marca, @modelo, @ano, @cor, @estado, @valor);";
    private const string countCodigo = "select COUNT(id) from tbl_Carro";

    public int cadastrarCarro(Carro c)
            {
                int codigo = 0;

                using (MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection(conexao))
                {
                    using(MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(insertCarro, conectar))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            conectar.Open();

                            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marca", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = c.Marca;
                            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modelo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = c.Modelo;
                            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ano", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = c.Ano;
                            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cor", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = c.Cor;
                            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = c.Estado;
                            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valor", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = c.Valor;

                            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            comando.CommandText = countCodigo;

                            codigo = Convert.ToInt32(comando.ExecuteScalar());

                        }
                        catch (MySqlException)
                        {
                           MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro ao executar a inserção do carro no banco de dados!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            conectar.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return codigo;
            }

class Carro
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Marca { get;set; }
        public string Modelo { get; set; }
        public int Ano { get; set; }
        public string Cor { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public double Valor { get; set; }


        public Carro()
        {
        }

        public Carro(int _id)
        {
            Id = _id;
        }

        public Carro(int _id, string _marca, string _modelo, int _ano, string _cor, string _estado, double _valor)
        {
            Id = _id;
            Marca = _marca;
            Modelo = _modelo;
            Ano = _ano;
            Cor = _cor;
            Estado = _estado;
            Valor = _valor;
        }

        public Carro(string _marca, string _modelo, int _ano, string _cor, string _estado, double _valor)
        {
            Marca = _marca;
            Modelo = _modelo;
            Ano = _ano;
            Cor = _cor;
            Estado = _estado;
            Valor = _valor;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Qual a linha em que a exceção acontece?

Comment: @carlosfigueira Na linha que executo o comando pela primeira vez comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Poste a exceção completa (mensagem + *stack trace*), fica mais fácil de saber o problema. Outra informação que também pode ser útil é a definição da classe `Carro`

Comment: @carlosfigueira Pronto coloquei StackTrace + a Classe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método [`SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) recebe como parâmetros o nome do parâmetro e o **valor** do parâmetro. Você está passando para ele o nome e o **tipo** do parâmetro. Como você passa um `SqlDbType` como o *valor* do parâmetro, alguma conversão (provavelmente para um dos parâmetros numéricos) está falhando.

Tente trocar este método pelo [`SqlParameterCollection.Add(string parameterName, SqlDbType sqlDbType)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s.aspx), que deve resolver este problema.

Comment: Obrigado, parei de informar o tipo e passei a informar o valor do do parametro com o AddWithValue e funcionou. Muito Obrigado e Boa Noite :)